# How to force HTML5/CSS3 navigation menu over the content

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I trying to force my navigation menu over the content. I have used z-index and overflow = visible. But it does not work. I don't want to make position relative because the menu will push the content down. I would just like the menu go over the content. Below is the code. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nav</title>
    <link href="nav.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="tabApp" >
  <nav>
    <ul> <span>The app</span>
        <li class="sub">
            <a href="shop.html">Version</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="#">V2</a>
                    <ul ng-controller="V2Ctrl">
                        <li ng-repeat = "v2 in V2s">{{v2}}</li>
                        <li><a href="one.html">One</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="#">V3</a>
                    <ul ng-controller="V3Ctrl">
                        <li ng-repeat = "v3 in V3s">{{v3}}</li>
                        <li><a href="one.html">One</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:alert('What are you talking about?');">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article class="tabs">

      <section id="home">
        <h2><a href="#home">Home</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab Home.</p>
      </section>

      <section id="table">
        <h2><a href="#table">table</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab tab.</p>
      </section>

      <section id="col">
        <h2><a href="#col">Columns</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab Columns.</p>
      </section>

  </article>

  <aside align="left">
    aside of content
  </aside>

  <footer align="bottom">
    <span>"Copyright&copy; 2016</span></span>
  </footer>

  <script>
      var app = angular.module('tabApp', []);
      app.controller('V2Ctrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.V2s = ['  10','  11','  12','  13','  14','  15','  16','  17','  18','  19','  20','  21','  22','  23','  24','  25','  26','  27','  28'];
      });  
      app.controller('V3Ctrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.V3s = ['  ','   SP1','   SP2','   SP3','   SP4','   SP5','   SP6','   SP7','   SP8','   SP9','   SP10'];
      });  
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
#logo{
    position: absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Helvetica Nueue", Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
}
nav {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
na ul span {
    width: 300px
    margin-top: 250%;;
}
nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    /*padding: 0.5em 2em;*/
    padding: 0.2em 3em;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav li > ul{
    display : none;
    margin-top:1px;
    background-color: #bbb;

}

nav li > ul li{
    display: block;
}

nav  li > ul li a {
    color: #111;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0.2em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}
nav li:hover > ul{
    position:absolute;
    display : block;
}
nav li > ul > li ul  {
    display: none;
    background-color: #888;
}
nav li > ul > li:hover > ul  {
    position:absolute;
    display : block;
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-3em;
}

nav ul > li.sub{
    background: url(ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_18dp.png) right center no-repeat;
    z-index: 5; 
    overflow: visible;
}

nav ul > li.sub li.sub{
    background: url(ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_18dp.png) right center no-repeat;
    z-index: 5; 
    overflow: visible;
}

/*****************************************************************************/
article.tabs
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
article.tabs section
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 0;
}
article.tabs section:first-child
{
    z-index: 1;
}
article.tabs section h2
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    height: 1.5em;
    top: -1.5em;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
article.tabs section:nth-child(2) h2
{
    left: 132px;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(3) h2
{
    left: 254px;
}

article.tabs section h2 a
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: 0 none;
}
article.tabs section:target,
article.tabs section:target h2
{
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
article.tabs section,
article.tabs section h2
{
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

footer 
{
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I added the code to jsfiddle.

[https://jsfiddle.net/3nkf8ken/1/](http://jsfiddle)

Comment: I would recommend putting the code in a jsfiddle, to make it easier for others to edit.

Comment: I just put the code there. Thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `z-index` property on your `nav` and `nav ul` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/masterspambot/hy3awqq9/1/

Comment: Can you explain further @AndreiGheorghiu? Menu overflows over content and shows in exact place. Seems to be working.

Comment: I fixed that just after i noticed i copied old version of fiddle. Thanks for pointing out ;)

Comment: masterspambot, you da the man:)   Really appreciate your help.